# previewFlutterUiGuides no funciona

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart

Tengo el código inicial de flutter (el contador) cuando se crea por primera vez un proyecto de flutter, tengo activado el previewFlutterUiGuides para ver las líneas.

[image: esta es de la que hablo]

Pero no se muestran las líneas correspondientes de las que hablo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, tengo activadas las 2 opciones pero aún así no funciona, en mi json igual lo tengo en true.
Otro problema que tengo es que no me detecta las variables clases u otras cosas que creé en flutter en el archivo: no me sale la opción de autocompletar ni en android studio ni en visual studio, no sé si me expliqué en esto último.

EJEMPLO:

```
class Empresa {
  String nombre;
  String propietario;
  int ingresoAnual;
}
```

Cuando quiero hacer referencia a esa clase

```
  Empresa _facebook = new Empresa("Facebook", "Mark Zuckerberg", 50000000);
```

No me lo detecta ni android ni visual.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Haz solo una pregunta por cada duda que tengas (esta pregunta en realidad tiene dos preguntas...) 2. Visual Studio != Visual Studio **Code**. 3. ¿Ya cerraste y abriste de nuevo VSCode?

Comment: ya, no se que era, pero se resolvio con flutter:uppgrate, gracias por el consejo leere el post :3